# How to parse large nested json objects?

Tags: javascript, json

[PasteBin JSON](https://pastebin.com/LdJdHthY)

I would like to get this as Object it says jsonlint is valid but parsing is not anyone help would appreciate

```
"Data":[{...},{...},] // structure build like this
```

when i try

```
JSON.parse(jsonparamter) <-- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 71
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

Comment: No he's not @adiga

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar my bad.

Comment: @adiga but why is this valid on jsonlint but cant parse it? i tried but it really does

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple levels of JSON encoded data so you will have to create a loop to decode the elements deeper in the JSON nest. Use the below code to see an example of accessing Data.Adress.Value in this dictionary

```js
// set up urls and headers for making HTTP req
corsurl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
jsonurl = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/vuecweML'
headerNames = ['Content-Type','Accept']
headerValues = [ 'application/json', 'application/json']


// Modular get request function that I use
function getRequest (baseRestURL, APIPath, headerNames, headerValues, callback) {
  var completeRestURL = baseRestURL + APIPath
  console.log('REST API URL: ' + completeRestURL)
  var method = 'GET'
  var url = completeRestURL
  var async = true
  var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request2.onload = function () {
    console.log('ONLOAD')
    var status = request2.status // HTTP response status, e.g., 200 for "200 OK"
    console.log(status)
    console.log(request2.responseText)
    var response = request2.responseText
    return callback(response)
  }
  request2.open(method, url, async)
  for (var i in headerNames) {
    request2.setRequestHeader(headerNames[i], headerValues[i])
  }
  request2.send(null)
 }
  
  
  
// Our code of interest  
getRequest(corsurl, jsonurl, headerNames, headerValues, response => {

  parsed = JSON.parse(response).Data //parse our data the first time, and get the data attribute from dictionary
  objects = JSON.parse(parsed) // parse a second time ( as data is JSON encoded twice )
  selection = JSON.parse(objects[0].Address)[0].Value // parse a third time and select an attribute
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = selection // Add it to our html to display
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'> Loading </div>
```

Comment: what if i get this as local string not from url, http

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar using it as a local string will work fine. I only used the HTTP request because I couldn't paste the json data you linked onto SO's javascript editor as it was to big. Without being able to paste it,  the only way to access it was via a HTTP request.

Comment: reason why i asking is i got similar problem but different is i get as local string; would help you my brain its shrink cause of it

Comment: what do you mean by local string? Can you paste your code in the question so I can understand? do you mean`localStorage.getItem()`?

Comment: I can't continue in chat, have to leave in about 5 minutes. If you update the question though I'll check it later though.